# Transforming $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} A^{T} \\ -A^{T} \end{smallmatrix}\right)^{T} x = -b$ after using Farkas Lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, optimization, transformation

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $u, b \in \mathbb R^{m}$.

I am close to proving:

$A x =b$ has a solution $\iff$ $b^{T}u \leq 0$ and $A^{T}u=0$.

Using Farkas Lemma I get to the point where

$\begin{pmatrix}  A^{T} \\ -A^{T}  \end{pmatrix}^{T} x = -b$ has a solution for $x\geq 0.$ $(**)$

What transformation step do I need to show that $Ax=b$ for any $x \in \mathbb R^{
n}$?

My Proof (how I got to $(**)$):

Let $b^{T}u \leq 0$ and $A^{T}u=0$ have a solution then $b^{T}u > 0 $ with $A^{T}u=0$ $(D')$has no solution,

we then rewrite $(D')$ as $-b^{T}u < 0 $ and $\begin{pmatrix}  A^{T} \\ -A^{T}  \end{pmatrix}u\geq 0$. By the Farkas Lemma this means that $\begin{pmatrix}  A^{T} \\ -A^{T}  \end{pmatrix}^{T}x=-b, x\geq 0$ has a solution.
And I know that

$\begin{pmatrix}  A^{T} \\ -A^{T}  \end{pmatrix}^{T}=(A,-A)$

But how can I manipulate $(A,-A)x=-b, x \geq 0$ to show that

$Ax=b$ for all $x$ ?

Another question that comes to mind is the validity of the equation $(A,-A)x=-b$ as $(A,-A)\in \mathbb R^{m\times 2n}$ while $x \in \mathbb R^{n}$, so $(A,-A)x$ does not make sense, or am I overthinking this?

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}  A^{T} \\ -A^{T}  \end{pmatrix}^{T}=(A, -A)$ but then multiplying it by $x$ would make no sense since $(A, -A) \in \mathbb R^{m\times 2n}$, while $x \in \mathbb R^{n}$

Comment: That means that your original equation does not make sense too. Maybe you should double check how you arrived at it.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I've updated to include my proof

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3158785/after-farkas-lemma-transforming-a-ax-b-into-ax-b